# Square wave -5 to +5 volt at 500 Hz

Tags: atmega, pwm, uart, rs232

I need to make a square wave -5 to +5 V at approx. 500 Hz - with small current. I have 0 (ground) and +5 V and a PWM (a [Waspmote](http://www.libelium.com/products/waspmote) with a ATmega1281 microcontroller). I think it would be possible to make the square wave with a UART/RS232 chip - but I'm not sure.

It's important that the square wave is shifting between -5 and +5 volts. Any ideas?

Comment: What's a 'Waspmote'? Include it in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this requirement would be in two parts:

1. Generating a -5 Volts power rail from the existing +5 and 0 Volt rails
2. Using PWM output fed to a comparator, to switch an output between these two rails.

For the first part, depending on the current requirements, here are two options:

The [Linear Technology LT1611](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1611f.pdf) is a inverting switching regulator can provide up to 150 mA at -5 Volts, from your +5 Volt source.

[image: LT1611 typical circuit]

For higher power requirements, the [OnSemi MC34063](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/MC34063A.pdf) inverting switching regulator can provide up to 500 mA without additional drive components, only a few passives, higher current with additional parts. It can provide a variable negative output voltage, from a positive power supply.

There is a simple to use [component calculator for the MC34063](http://www.nomad.ee/micros/mc34063a/index.shtml) available, that makes designing for the part simple.

---

The second part of the requirement is then very well met by the comparator solutions proposed in the other answers.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way I can see is to use an 1 op amp as a comparator. (probably cheaper than a dedicated RS232 chip and more available especially at local shops)

Have a look at [Comparitor Operation](http://www.wisc-online.com/objects/ViewObject.aspx?ID=SSE4603).

When V+ > V- the output will go to the positive rail (+5V)
When V+ < V- the output will go to the negative rail (-5V)

You can set a threshold at V-, like at 2.0V, so that the output will only change when V+ is greater than 2V or less than 2V.

Comment: OP states that they have only a +5 and 0 Volt supply, but desire a +5 to -5 Volt excursion. This solution will not work.

Comment: Thanks - is there any specific type you have in mind?

Comment: For your voltage range and frequency, whatever easily available opamp you can get your hands on would do. Even the infamous 741 would suffice. However, you DO need access to -5V. Either use the inverting switching regulator mentioned by @AnindoGhosh or even something as simply as a 5V battery in addition to your existing 5V supply.

Comment: Thanks!  Well... I'm quite new to electronics, but I now got the -5 volt (using the MC34063 chip). And I got a TL071CDP op amp, but I can't get it to work. I'm confused about the inputs: +/- offset and the +/- Vcc - which one to use and how?

Comment: OK - works now :-)  Thanks to [hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/square.html) great calculator!!

Answer (score -3):

Use a comparator with a +5v and -5v supply.

Comment: Could you add some example schematics or such? Even a diagram would be great.. Of course, if you have time.

Comment: OP states that they have only a +5 and 0 Volt supply, but desire a +5 to -5 Volt excursion. This solution will not work.

Comment: He needs to provide a -5V supply. That should have been obvious!